# How to display the attributes of my existing model in a Dropdown with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu

Please how can i display the attribute_array in a Dropdown in my form file.

i have this:

```
<%= simple_form_for @rule do |f| %>

    <div class="form-group"> 

      <%= f.input :id  ,class:"form-control form-control-lg" %>

      <% attribute_array =  AttributeType.all.map { |attribute| [ attribute.value, attribute.level, attribute.name, attribute.code] } %>
      <%= options_for_select(attributes_array) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= f.input(
      :name_of_field,
      label: "Action",
      collection: AttributeType.all.map { |attribute| [ attribute.value, attribute.name] ,
      input_html: { class: "your-class" }
    ) %>
```

Comment: thank you, i tried that but it dosen't show a list of collection